# How to solve a differential equation? $y'-y^2+y\cdot\cos(x)+\sin(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is clear that the expression $y(x) = \cos(x)$ is suitable. But I can’t figure out how to find the rest of the roots if they exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to classify this as Riccati equation. Then you know that any other solution can be obtained from $y=y_p+\frac1z$ where the equation for $z$ reduces to a linear first order DE.

---

The other variant is to set $y=-\frac{u'}{u}$. Inserted this gives
$$
-\frac{u''}{u}+\frac{u'^2}{u^2}-\frac{u'^2}{u^2}-\frac{u'}{u}\cos x+\sin x=0\\
\implies -u''-u'\cos x+u\sin x=0\\
\implies u'+u\cos x=C
$$
This integrated nicely in this case. Generally this does not happen.

For $C=0$ one recovers $y=-\frac{u'}{u}=\cos x$. For $C\ne 0$ the resulting integral is not symbolically solvable.